# How can I change wheel speed in ScrollPane component AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a way to change wheel speed in ScrollPane component AS3?

Comment: do you mean changing the scroll speed when using the mouse wheel ?

Comment: Please see this links: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5221754/1563878) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120420/flex-list-scroll-speed-with-mouse-wheel), maybe will be useful.